# Problemas con método paint en java - Stackoverflow error

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de hacer que un simple rectángulo se mueva a través de una pantalla usando KeyEvents, mi problema viene cuando ejecuto el método paint en donde creo que esta mi error, pues aunque el programa muestra el rectángulo, si lo muevo un poco sale el error "StackOverFlowError" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

indagando he llegado a pensar que esto se deba a que estoy llamando demasiadas veces el método KeyEvents dentro del método paint, pero aun así no como solucionar esto, he tratado del hacer el método addKeyListener estático, pero no se como lograr esto. Aca dejo el codigo de la clase como tal.

```
public class Dibujo extends JPanel {

int min = 0;
int max = 600;

Jugador jugador = new Jugador();

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Métodos que ayudan a que el JPanel acepten KeyPressed events
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
    moverJugador();

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    jugador.dibujarJugador(g);

    super.repaint();

}


public void moverJugador(){
    addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int codigoKey = e.getKeyCode();
            if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                jugador.setPosY(jugador.getPosY() - 0.002f);
            }
            if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                jugador.setPosY(jugador.getPosY() + 0.002f);
            }
            if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                jugador.setPosX(jugador.getPosX() - 0.002f);
            }
            if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                jugador.setPosX(jugador.getPosX() + 0.002f);
            }
            if(codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final solucione el problema creando una clase especifica para el teclado en la cual implementaba en ella KeyListener de modo que aunque el método addKeyListener() nunca pueda ser llamado de forma estatica, una clase si puede.

**CLASE TECLADO**

```
public class Teclado implements KeyListener {

//Con implements la clase teclado ahora quedara siendo y teniendo las
//propiedades de un KeyListener, de modo que ahora se puede añadir la clase 
//como tal a un addKeyListener(teclado);
public boolean arriba;
public boolean abajo;
public boolean izquierda;
public boolean derecha;

public Teclado() {

}

public boolean getArriba(){
    return arriba;
}

public boolean getAbajo(){
    return abajo;
}

public boolean getIzquierda(){
    return izquierda;
}

public boolean getDerecha(){
    return derecha;
}

public void setArriba(boolean arriba){
    this.arriba = arriba;
}

public void setAbajo(boolean abajo){
    this.abajo = abajo;
}
public void setIzquierda(boolean izquierda){
    this.izquierda = izquierda;
}
public void setDerecha(boolean derecha){
    this.derecha = derecha;
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent ke) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
    int codigoKey = e.getKeyCode();
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        setArriba(true);
    }
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        setAbajo(true);
    }
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        setIzquierda(true);
    }
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        setDerecha(true);
    }
    if(codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
    int codigoKey = e.getKeyCode();
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        setArriba(false);
    }
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        setAbajo(false);
    }
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        setIzquierda(false);
    }
    if (codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        setDerecha(false);
    }
    if(codigoKey == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

**CLASE DIBUJO**

```
Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
static Teclado teclado = new Teclado();

float posJugadorX = 50;
float posJugadorY = 50;

public Dibujo(){
    addKeyListener(teclado);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    //Métodos que ayudan a que el JPanel acepte KeyPressed events
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocusInWindow();
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    jugador.dibujarJugador(g, getPosX(), getPosY());
    super.repaint();
}

 private float getPosY(){
    if(teclado.getArriba()){
        return this.posJugadorY = posJugadorY - 0.02f;
    }
    if(teclado.getAbajo()){
        return this.posJugadorY = posJugadorY + 0.02f;
    }
    return this.posJugadorY;
}

private float getPosX(){
    if(teclado.getDerecha()){
        return this.posJugadorX = posJugadorX + 0.02f;
    }
    if(teclado.getIzquierda()){
        return this.posJugadorX = posJugadorX - 0.02f;
    }
    return this.posJugadorX;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe, casi con seguridad, a que en tu método `paint()` estás llamando a `moverJugador()` que cada vez que se ejecuta agrega un listener. Esto está, casi seguramente, mal. `paint()` (y con toda probabilidad `moverJugador()`) es un método que se llamará muchas veces: es llamado cada vez que al hilo de eventos de awt le parece que hay que "repintar" un área (o, secundariamente, cuando tu propio código ha invocado "repaint"). Ese no es de ningún modo el momento para agregar un "listener"! El listener debería ser agregado (típicamente) una sola vez, cuando el objeto es creado.

Comment: Exactamente, el problema es que no se como llamarlo una sola vez dentro de este método, tampoco se con seguridad si un addKeyListener tiene alguna forma de hacerse estático.

Comment: Repito: el listener debes agregarlo al momento de crear el objeto, no al momento de ejecutar su metodo paint() o moverJugador(). NO entiendo como hablas de hacer estatico un metodo que nunca puede serlo, debe estar atado a una instancia.